# How convert telegram session to json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I searched the internet for a solution, but couldn't find anything
I tried to parse the session data, but the problem is that you can't get all the data, I couldn't find "register time"
What I want to see in Json:

```
{"session_file": "6285351202414", "phone": "6285351202414", "register_time": 1665007347, "app_id": id, "app_hash": "hash", "sdk": "iOS", "app_version": "1.52.10 Z", "device": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/100.0.5120.93 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1", "last_check_time": 1666735347, "avatar": "img/default.png", "first_name": "TGBOSS", "last_name": "Accounts", "username": "shykhiworyvi2", "sex": 1, "lang_pack": "en", "system_lang_pack": "en-US", "twoFA": "shykhiworyvi2_5631309146", "ipv6": false, "status": "ok", "status_time": 1666735347, "is_old": false, "proxy": []}
```

Comment: Can you enter the complete code you are trying out?

Comment: Did you find any solution I'm also looking for same thing.